# Android custom keyboard Row class not found exception

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a custom keyboard implementation in android.
So far i have declared my keyboard layout in an xml file:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Row>
    <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Row>
```

When I try to inflate this layout I get following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Row
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at com.mykeyboard.MyKeyboardService.onCreateInputView(MyKeyboardService.java:23)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:967)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1320)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1295)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:398)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Row in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mykeyboard-2.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4775):    ... 19 more
```

Looks like it can not find `android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Row in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader` but what does this mean?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the available ctors for Keyboard.Row. You can't instantiate one of these objects without the parent Keyboard object. That error is because the class loader can't find the constructor that is being invoked.

To fix your issue, just surround what you have in a Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff, that seems like an invalid keyboard file. The JavaDocs for `Keyboard` show a sample like this:

```
<Keyboard
         android:keyWidth="%10p"
         android:keyHeight="50px"
         android:horizontalGap="2px"
         android:verticalGap="2px" >
     <Row android:keyWidth="32px" >
         <Key android:keyLabel="A" />
         ...
     </Row>
     ...
</Keyboard>
```

And, the SoftKeyboard app in the SDK shows XML of a similar fashion: root `Keyboard` element, with nested `Row` elements, and `Key` elements inside those.

You might want to start with the SDK sample and modify from there.

Comment: I started from that file, but this gives following error.

http://pastebin.com/rkwaUcMe

Looks the same to me, can not find class but why it can't?

Comment: @Wouter: Try building the SoftKeyboard SDK sample in its entirety. If that works, start trying to figure out what is different between your app and that SDK sample. If the SDK sample does not work, then we have bigger problems... :-)